# scroll view resizing

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I have a problem with `ScrollView` component.
How to prevent stretching of `ScrollView`?

I have a `LinearLayout` with `weight_sum = 2` and in it an `ImageView` with `layout_weight = 1` and a `ScrollView` with `layout_weight = 1`

It looks fine when `ScrollView` has 2, 3 elements, that means that it doesn't need to scroll.
When I add more elements the `ScrollView` resizes, its height gets bigger and bigger, and the `ImageView` gets smaller.

Height of those items is `wrap_content`.

How to prevent that problem?

Code:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pregamePlayerNames"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/en_player_names" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/pregamePlayerNamesScroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/home_player_names_ram"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are giving `weight` to the layout no need to specify the `height`

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/pregamePlayerNames"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/en_player_names" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >


     .................
     ................
```

Answer (score 1):

set the items with weight to height=0dp if you want to dynamically divide the space.

Comment: hmmm...i've tried that...doesnt work :/ everything gets sthreched and looks ugly.